# Paint not working on canvas.drawVertices?

Tags: java, android, canvas, draw, vertices

My drawVertices(...) has been provided with paint as below

```
   val paint = Paint().apply {
        style = Paint.Style.STROKE
        strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
        strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
        isAntiAlias = true
        textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
        textSize = resources.dpToPx(30)
        color = Color.RED
        strokeWidth = resources.dpToPx(8)
    }

    val verts = floatArrayOf(0f, 0f, width.toFloat(), 0f, width/2f, height/2f,
        width/2f, height/2f, 0f, height.toFloat(), width.toFloat(), height.toFloat())

    canvas.drawVertices(
        Canvas.VertexMode.TRIANGLES,
        verts.size, verts, 0,
        null, 0,
        null, 0,
        indices, 0, indices.size,
        paint
    )
```

However the vertices is drawn is still back in color, and with a seemingly 1px with line. So regardless of what I change my `paint` into (e.g. `Color.RED`)

Is the `paint` not really used in `drawVertices`? (I try put `null`, it fail to compile)